# Mercurial branching - share changes between bookmark-branches

Tags: version-control, mercurial, branching-and-merging

Basically I have repository with such structure:
A(branch:stable) -> B(branch:dev) -> C(branch:dev, bookmark:feature) (and similar siblings)

In one of C sibling (to say - E) I made some changes that I want to share with all other bookmark-branches.
How can I properly do that? I thought to merge E with B, and then merge from that new commit to other bookmark-branches (siblings of C) - but Hg throws an error - "nothing to merge", when  I trying to merge E to B.
If try to merge E to A - Hg handles it well, and I need to do exactly same, but just in inside single named-branch (here - dev).

How can I properly achieve needed effect?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to merge from E to B, because E is a direct descendant of B in the same branch (no merges in between). You can do `hg bookmark B -r E` to move B's bookmark up E, which is essentially what the merge would be doing anyway. Afterwards, you should set which bookmark you want to be active, lest you accidentally wind up with B tracking your current head and E stuck behind. You can then merge the other siblings of C no problem.

Of course, if you just want to merge, you can also directly merge in the changes from E:

```
hg update C # or other siblings
hg merge B
hg commit -m'Merged in changes from B'
```

Merging E to A works because they're in different branches.